# UIImageView created in UICollectionView remains black

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My imageViews still doesn't display an image, would be very grateful if someone could point to what is going wrong.

Here's the collection view function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL ID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: cell.contentView.bounds)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "gear.png")
    cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    return cell
}
```

And in viewDidLoad I have:

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CELL ID")
```

The cell is identified with the correct CELL ID and I know that part is working because I can set the background color of these cells and it'll show up. The imageView shows up black. I can set the background color at the same time I set the imageView and the color will show.

Comment: Check whether do you have image named gear.png & even check the extension

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have image Named gear and also check the extension.